24.04 with pulseaudio, jack and cadence instead of pipewire
In 24.04, I'd like to replace how I have things in 22.04. In 22.04 I use Cadence to bridge pulseaudio to jack. Then Reaper and Renoise and other music software run as Jack clients.
Running 23.10 (and I presume the same with 24.04), it uses pipewire rather than pulseaudio as with 22.04. Now with Cadence, it was easy to set things up with pulseaudio bridged into jack. Then audio software like Reaper could use Jack.
On 23.10 (I have one thinkpad running 23.10, most are running 22.04) with pipewire, even though pipewire claims to offer a Jack API, Reaper and Renoise do not work as jack clients. So I'm wondering if I can replicate the pulseaudio+jack setup from 22.04. I won't upgrade to 24.04 as running Reaper low latency is important to me.
Or possibly I'm doing something wrong in 23.10. I can run Jack (via Cadence), and then Reaper can use Jack, but I can't bridge desktop audio as a Jack client.

https://ubuntustudio.org/audio-configuration/
